# Create folders in the active workbook's path from a list of folder names on the active sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I need several folders. I have a list with their names and have code but don't know how to loop it through my list. A few days ago I asked about fixing code that exports a file in a newly created folder. Now I am trying to modify that code, but it is not working:

```
Dim strFilename As String, _
strDirname As String, _
strPathname As String, _
strDefpath As String, _
SheetToExport As String, _
WbMaster As Workbook, _
WbCopy As Workbook


On Error Resume Next ' If directory exist goto next line
strDirname = Range("D81").Value ' New directory name
strFilename = Range("D8").Value 'New file name

Set WbMaster = Application.ActiveWorkbook
SheetToExport = Range("A1").Value 'Or specify UserForm output

strDefpath = WbMaster.Path 'Default path name

If IsEmpty(strDirname) Then Exit Sub
If IsEmpty(strFilename) Then Exit Sub

MkDir strDefpath & "\" & strDirname
strPathname = strDefpath & "\" & strDirname & "\" & strFilename 'create total string

WbMaster.Sheets(SheetToExport).Copy
Set WbCopy = Application.ActiveWorkbook

WbCopy.SaveAs Filename:=strPathname & ".xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
            ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

ClosingWb = MsgBox("Do you wish to close the exported file?",vbYesNo,"Close exported file")
If ClosingWb <> vbNo Then WbCopy.Close
```

I tried to remove the part where it creates a new file but it starts breaking all the time.

Comment: which part "creates a new file" (the `wbCopy.SaveAs` line?) and what does "breaking all the time" actually mean?  IOW, can you describe your *actual* problem?  Should be pretty easy to diagnose if you can tell us what the problem is...

Comment: I want that my `xlsm´ only creates folders, with names from my list.
It's not working how i do it... and i don't know how i could loop through..

In the end i want to paste my list in and it should create my folders when i press a button

Comment: "Not working" and "breaking all the time" don't tell us anything about your actual problem. Where is your "list"? What errors do you get in the code?  How do the output differ from your expectations?  **DO NOT** respond in the comments, EDIT your original question to include these details and then maybe someone can help you...

Comment: You say "I want that my `xlsm´ only creates folders", but in your code you're creating workbooks and saving them in new folders.  Which is it?

Comment: yes, but i want that it only creates folders. I tried to remove the file creating stuff but its not working then.... and i don'T know how to loop through cells when i need folders with the names in A50:A200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't contain a loop.  Depending on where in your workbook this list of folder names is contained, and how static the size of that list is (based on your code I'm assuming that it is contained within a set of cells in column D, but there is also other stuff in that column so you wouldn't be able to use any standard method of handling a variable list size), you would need a loop that looks through that list.

Also, you intend to create all these folders in the path of the workbook containing this code, otherwise you would need to set your path name to something else...

Let's say your list is of variable size, doesn't contain any blanks, and is contained in some unknown number of cells starting in A50 but never any farther than A100. Then your loop could look like this:

```
    Dim strDirname As String, _
    strPathname As String, _
    strDefpath As String, _
    WbMaster As Workbook

    For i = 1 to WorksheetFunction.Counta(Range("A50:A100"))
        strDirname = Range("A" & i).Value ' New directory name
        Set WbMaster = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        strDefpath = WbMaster.Path 'Default path name
        If Dir(strDefpath & "\" & strDirname) = "" Then
            MkDir strDefpath & "\" & strDirname
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: The code in my question was from an other project of mine....

I only need folders no files.... only folders.. :/

Comment: That's even easier then.  All you have to do is take out the parts of this code that actually create and save a new workbook and replace them with code that creates your folders.  You still haven't answered the question of where exactly your list of folder names is within your workbook though.  That's an important one...

Comment: Lets take A50:A100 how does this matter? you always can change this...

I'm not good at programming... but i'll try. i bet it doesn'T work after..

Comment: and it's not working anymore... i only removed the  file saving stuff.. ):

Comment: Well, the code is looking at a specific set of cells.  I set it up to cycle through D75:D100 (because the code you posted showed it looking at D81 a single time...)  Try my edit.  This should just create folders for you if your list of folder names is in D75 to D100, and you want them to be created in the workbook's path.

Comment: thanks, i changed that places where the names where often ^^...

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late to jump in with an answer....

If your folder names (full paths) are on Sheet1 range C1:C4.
The Main procedure will step through each cell in the range, calling the CreateFolder procedure to create all folders/subfolders as required in the path string.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C4")
        CreateFolder rCell.Value
    Next rCell 
End Sub


Sub CreateFolder(Folder)
On Error Resume Next
Dim objFSO As Object: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Folder <> "" Then
        If Not objFSO.FileExists(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(Folder)) Then
            Call CreateFolder(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(Folder))
        End If
        objFSO.CreateFolder (Folder)
    End If
End Sub
```

So, for example, I have set up a dynamic folder name:
In cell A1 enter the formula `=TODAY()`
in cell C1 enter the formula: `="C:\Test\" & TEXT($A$1+ROW(),"mm mmm yyyy\\dd (ddd)")` and drag down to row 4.
This will turn the date into a folder name, using the row number to increment the date.
You'll get four folders named `C:\Test\10 Oct 2015\08 (Thu)` to `C:\Test\10 Oct 2015\11 (Sun)`